# Cannot get autocompletion on Django Model Manager in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm trying to use autocompletion to get methods like filter, count, create, etc. in PyCharm, but I can't seem to grab them from the objects attribute. It seems like this specific attribute is not working - since PyCharm provides autocompletion for the class itself, for example, just not objects. I've tried refreshing the virtual environment as well, but it seems like it might just not be a supported features. It doesn't autocomplete in either Pycharm 2020.3 or Pycharm 2021.2., or in abstract or concrete classes.

[image: For example self gets models.Models functions and attributes, but objects does not.]

Note: I'm using Pycharm Professional. This is what my Django settings look like:

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/django-support7.html

Comment: self.objects is not set at that moment and it is not intended to be used in that way.  What is the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: That was just an example, I was just trying to figure out how to get autocompletion to work, but I wasn't actually trying to use self there. I did figure it out I think, but thank you for the support.

Answer (score 5):

I had a exactly the same problem (PyCharm 2021.3 Professional Edition / Windows 11 / Python 3.9 / Django 3.2.x). My project was created using `cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django` template, which includes the `django-stubs` package for mypy (https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/requirements/local.txt#L17). This package seems to break autocomplete support for Django in PyCharm – here are the relevant bug reports https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37744 and https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/555.

After uninstalling `django-stubs` (`pip uninstall django-stubs`), PyCharm started autocompleting again.

Answer (score 1):

Django specific completion is in PyCharm Professional only.

You'll also need to make sure Django integration is set up in the PyCharm preferences (search for Django in there).

Comment: I'm using Pycharm Professional, I've updated the question. Django integration is enabled, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out the problem actually, I don't think it's a Pycharm problem (Pycharm configuration is fine I think), I think it has to do with the fact that Model.objects is abstract because Pycharm says it's of type `Any`:

[image: Type is Any, not Manager]

To get code completion, it looks like I actually have to create a subclass of `models.Manager`, and then I have access to the Manager methods:

[image: Now I have access to Manager methods]

Then, I set the objects attribute in the model to be that manager. So, I don't have direct access to objects it seems.